# Reconstructing the path that gives the maximum path sum in a matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to find a maximum path sum in the matrix. The starting position must be in `a[0][0]` (top-left) and the ending position must be in `a[n][m]` (bottom-right). The move is only allowed to the right, down, or diagonal.

Here is my solution:

```
public class Main {

    public static int maxa(int[][] a) {
        int m = a.length, n = a[0].length;
        int[][] dp = new int[m][n];
        dp[0][0] = a[0][0];

        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
            dp[i][0] = dp[i - 1][0] + a[i][0];
        }
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            dp[0][j] = dp[0][j - 1] + a[0][j];
        }

        System.out.println("Route Path: ");
        System.out.print(a[0][0] + " ");
        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = findMax(dp[i - 1][j], dp[i][j - 1], dp[i-1][j-1]) + a[i][j];
                if (a[i - 1][j] > a[i][j - 1]) {
                    System.out.print(a[i - 1][j] + " ");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(a[i][j - 1] + " ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print(a[m - 1][n - 1] + " ");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Result: ");
        return dp[m - 1][n - 1];
    }
public static int findMax(int num1, int num2, int num3) {
    if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3)
        return num1;
    else if (num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3)
        return num2;
    else
        return num3;
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int MAX = 30;
        int MIN = -30;
        Random random = new Random();

        System.out.print("Enter values of Rows: ");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter values of Columns: ");
        int m = input.nextInt();
        int[][] myMatrix = new int[n][m];

        for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < m; col++) {
                // myMatrix[row][col] = random.nextInt(MAX - MIN) + MIN;
                myMatrix[row][col] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your Random Matrix: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                System.out.print(myMatrix[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(maxa(myMatrix));
    }
}
```

The result of the sum is correct but my code gives the wrong route path.

For example, if I have a 3x3 matrix = `[{1,2,3},{4,-5,6},{7-8,9}]`, then the result sum I get is 22 which is correct, but the route path I get is `1 4 3 -5 8 9` which is wrong. I expected my route path output to be `1 4 8 9`.

What can I do to fix the problem and produce the correct path?

Comment: @ggorlen I just edited the question. Thanks for remind me

Comment: The decision about the next step to take is being made while finding the max.  It makes most sense to accumulate the path there rather than with separate logic that's  subject to being wrong (and in this case is).

Comment: @Gene That's what I want to do but I stuck on that :(

Comment: You already say `if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3) return num1;`. This means you're selecting to use `num1`.  So print it.  `if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3) { System.out.print(num1 + " ");  return num1; }`. Do that for all 3 cases.  Then remove the printing logic you currently have.  It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Gene I did it but the Route Path of the a = [{1,2,3},{4-5,6}{-7,8,9}] will be '1 5 6 5 13 9' which is still wrong because the correct path will be '1 4 8 9'

Comment: Where are you getting 8 from? The matrix you gave was `[{1,2,3},{4,-5,6},{7-8,9}]` and even if `-8` was a typo where you meant `8`, then the expected output should be 29 with a path of `[1, 4, 7, 8, 9]`, if I'm not mistaken, rather than 22. If it's `-8`, I'd expect 21 to be the max path sum with a path of `[1, 2, 3, 6, 9]`.

Comment: @ggorlen yeah it's type. I meant  a = [{1,2,3},{4-5,6}{-7,8,9}] so the path will be 1 4 8 9 = 22

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow your expected output, but the inline prints are generally not a great approach to the problem. Generally, you want to compute it without a side effect and return it so the caller can use the result programmatically, optionally to print.

In any case, your printing condition `if (a[i - 1][j] > a[i][j - 1])` isn't enough to differentiate which of 3 possible moves was chosen on the best path. We need to find the largest of 3 subproblems in the DP table, not the input matrix -- looking at `a` is meaningless because it's only a local maxima at best.

In the case of a tie, it doesn't matter which move we pick from the DP table, all tied subproblems have equally maximal path scores.

While it's possible to figure out which number was taken along the way up by making that 3-way comparison, the typical(?) approach I'm familiar with for DP is to backtrack from `dp[m-1][n-1]` to `dp[0][0]` and reconstruct the path based on the DP table. It's free lunch from a time complexity standpoint and lets you separate the logic into a distinct function.

The logic for rebuilding the path is:

- Start at `i = m - 1, j = n - 1` (the bottom-right corner).
- Repeat until `i == 0` and `j == 0` (the top-left corner):

  - Add `a[i][j]` to the path.
  - If `i > 0` and `j > 0`, find the best of `dp[i-1][j], dp[i-1][j-1], dp[i][j-1]`. If the best was `[i-1][j-1]`, decrement both `i` and `j` by 1 -- we took a diagonal move; otherwise decrement either `i` or `j` depending on which move was better.
  - Otherwise, `i == 0` or `j == 0` and the path is on a top or left edge and we'll just decrement `i` or `j` until we get to the goal.
- Add `a[0][0]` to the path, reverse it and return it.

Here's a proof of concept:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {
    public static int maxPathSum(int[][] a) {
        final var table = makeDPTable(a);

        if (table.length > 0 && table[0].length > 0) {
            return table[table.length-1][table[0].length-1];
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Integer> maxPath(int[][] a) {
        return reconstructPath(makeDPTable(a), a);
    }

    private static ArrayList<Integer> reconstructPath(int dp[][], int a[][]) {
        final int m = a.length;

        if (m == 0) {
            return new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }

        final int n = a[0].length;
        final var path = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = m - 1, j = n - 1; i > 0 || j > 0;) {
            path.add(a[i][j]);

            if (i > 0 && j > 0) {
                final int bestIdx = indexOfMax(
                    dp[i-1][j-1], 
                    dp[i][j-1], 
                    dp[i-1][j]
                );

                switch (bestIdx) {
                    case 0: i--;
                    case 1: j--; break;
                    case 2: i--; break;
                }
            }
            else if (i > 0) {
                i--;
            }
            else {
                j--;
            }
        }

        path.add(a[0][0]);
        Collections.reverse(path);
        return path;
    }

    private static int[][] makeDPTable(int[][] a) {
        final int m = a.length;

        if (m == 0) {
            return new int[0][0];
        }

        final int n = a[0].length;
        final var dp = new int[m][n];
        dp[0][0] = a[0][0];

        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
            dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + a[i][0];
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            dp[0][j] = dp[0][j-1] + a[0][j];
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
                dp[i][j] = a[i][j] + max(
                    dp[i-1][j], 
                    dp[i][j-1], 
                    dp[i-1][j-1]
                );
            }
        }

        return dp;
    }

    private static int max(int ...nums) {
        if (nums.length == 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("nums cannot be empty");
        }

        int largest = nums[0];

        for (int num : nums) {
            largest = Math.max(num, largest);
        }

        return largest;
    }

    private static int indexOfMax(int ...nums) {
        if (nums.length == 0) {
            return -1;
        }

        int largest = nums[0];
        int idx = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[i] > largest) {
                largest = nums[i];
                idx = i;
            }
        }

        return idx;
    }

    private static void print(int[][] m) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(StringUtils.padLeft(m[i][j], 3));
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var tests = new TestCase[] {
            new TestCase(
                new int[][] {
                    {1, 2, 3},
                    {4,-5, 6},
                    {7,-8, 9},
                },
                new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 6, 9)),
                21
            ),
            new TestCase(
                new int[][] {
                    {1, 2, 3},
                    {4,-5, 6},
                    {7, 8, 9},
                },
                new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7, 8, 9)),
                29
            ),
            new TestCase(
                new int[][] {
                    {1, 2, 3, 20},
                    {4,-5, 6, -5},
                    {7, 8, 9, 10},
                },
                new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10)),
                39
            ),
            new TestCase(
                new int[][] {
                    {1, 2, 3,  -2},
                    {4,-5, -1, 20},
                    {0, 0, 9,  10},
                },
                new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 20, 10)),
                36
            ),
            new TestCase(
                new int[][] {
                    {-1, -2, -3, -2},
                    {-4, -5, -1, -2},
                },
                new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(-1, -2, -1, -2)),
                -6
            ),
            new TestCase(new int[][] {}, new ArrayList<Integer>(), 0),
        };

        for (var testCase : tests) {
            if (maxPathSum(testCase.m) != testCase.expectedSum) {
                print(testCase.m);
                System.out.println("got sum:  " + maxPathSum(testCase.m));
                System.out.println("expected: " + testCase.expectedSum + "\n");
            }

            if (!maxPath(testCase.m).equals(testCase.expectedPath)) {
                print(testCase.m);
                System.out.println("got path: " + maxPath(testCase.m));
                System.out.println("expected: " + testCase.expectedPath + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestCase {
    public final int[][] m;
    public final ArrayList<Integer> expectedPath;
    public final int expectedSum;

    public TestCase(
        int[][] m,
        ArrayList<Integer> expectedPath,
        int expectedSum
    ) {
        this.m = m;
        this.expectedPath = expectedPath;
        this.expectedSum = expectedSum;
    }
}

class StringUtils {
    public static <T> String padLeft(T t, int n) {
        return String.format("%" + n + "s", t);  
    }
}
```